# How to stack cards based on length in Semantic Grid

Tags: reactjs, grid-layout, semantic-ui-react

I'm using React.js and Semantic UI. I use the Grid from Semantic UI to place cards (boxes) in a grid.

How can I make the grid rows stack like the image under? I want the Card element row to go to the column that is shortest at that point? Is there a way to to that?

[image]

Currently it is just leaving a bit gap between the blue and the green (which equals the difference between the blue and red). This is my code at the moment:

```
<Grid stackable columns={2}>
    {
        props.list.map((aProject) => (
            <Grid.Column key={aProject.id}>
                <ProjectCard project={aProject} />
            </Grid.Column>
        )
    }
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library for your use case.
https://github.com/dantrain/react-stonecutter
I hope this can help you